# Eclipse: How do you change the highlight color of the currently selected method/expression?

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse, when your cursor is placed on a method (or other things), other places the method exists are highlighted. I'd like to change the color of this highlight, but after scouring the eclipse preferences many times in all 3 places, I have yet to find it.

Any of you `Eclipse` gurus know where to find this option?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

After running around in the Preferences dialog, the following is the location at which the highlight color for "occurrences" can be changed:

`General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations`

Look for `Occurences` from the *Annotation types* list.

Then, be sure that `Text as highlighted` is selected, then choose the desired color.

---

And, a picture is worth a thousand words...

[image: Preferences dialog]
<sub>(source: [coobird.net](http://coobird.net/img/eclipse-occurences-1.png))</sub>

[image: Image showing occurences highlighted in orange.]
<sub>(source: [coobird.net](http://coobird.net/img/eclipse-occurences-2.png))</sub>

Comment: Also change "Write Occurences" too for changing the highlighting where the variables is defined.

Comment: Very nice. When a Java guy sees "annotations" they immediately think about Java annotations which have nothing to do with this setting. But since it's under the regular TEXT Editor area instead of the Java Editor settings, the term means something entirely different. Anyway, the Eclipse guys need to change this setting's color to Orange by default, looking at the votes here it's obvious there's a number of people who hate the low contrast default...

Comment: It's different in Eclipse 3 Mars. Remember to get the "Read" and "Wrte" occurrences. Here's a screenshot of how it looks when editing for PHP: http://i.imgur.com/3H1GfYO.png

Comment: I needed Javascript Occurrences for Javascript after switching to dark mode

Answer (score 7):

For those working in Titanium Studio, the item is a little different:  It's under the "Titanium Studio" Themes tab.

The color to change is the "Selection" one in the top right.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

1 - right click the highlight whose color you want to change

2 - select "Properties" in the popup menu

3 - choose the new color (as [coobird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17172/coobird) suggested)

This solution is easy because you dont have to search for the highlight by its name ("Ocurrence" or "Write Ocurrence" etc), just right click and the appropriate window is shown.

Comment: Yes, this works if you right click the highlight color in the scroll bar that is meant to correspond with the location of the highlighted word in the source and click "Preferences...". Took me forever to realize that I was trying to edit the Matching Tags annotation type.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using eclipse with PHP package and want to change highlighted colour then there is slight difference to above answer.

1. Right click on highlighted word
2. Select 'Preferences'
3. Go to General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations. Now look for "PHP elements 'read' occurrences" and "PHP elements 'write' occurrences". You can select your desired colour there.

[image: Change Highlighted text colour in Eclips with PHP]

Answer (score 1):

1. right click the highlight whose color you want to change
2. select "Preference"
3. ->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations->Occurrences->Text as Hightlited->color.
4. Select "Preference ->java->Editor->Restore Defaults

Comment: This is a copy of the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

in my case (Eclipse IDE 2021-06), dark theme, the issue was with the background color of "C/C++ Write Occurrences".

On each click over a variable being written in the code, the editor highlights all occurrences of that variable.

You can find this setting here:

General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations
and then select 'C/C++ Write Occurrences'.
And finally change che Color property.