# How to change search background color in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I've been searching for about 40 minutes now and this is just so frustrating...

The standard search result background color in eclipse is freaking white and black. Everytime I search something I have to scan the screen for like 50 seconds before I find the spot where Eclipse has found something. I don't know which goon set it this way but he must be working with the goon who programmed the interface for configuring the colors... I can't find it.

Where do I change the background color of search results?

I feel ashamed to have to ask this here... but the things I've tried, like setting it in general>editors>text-editors>annotations didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing highlighting color in a theme from Eclipse color theme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635149/changing-highlighting-color-in-a-theme-from-eclipse-color-theme)

Comment: Eclipse has the most weird and disturbing preferences menu, can't find anything by yourself, and even on the web, most people are truly lost or just cannot explain the differences between two distinct options (and where the f*ck it was already ?!)

Answer (score 57):

In the Eclipse menu bar:
Windows->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations

Then scroll down to "Search Results" and set the highlighted text color.

This works for Eclipse Helios and Eclipse Juno.  I haven't tested other versions.

Comment: If you're looking for when you doubleclick on an object to get all the references highlighted, then you need to use the annotation type for Occurrences.

Comment: Oh, thank G*d. Have been trying to figure this out for . . . weeks?

Comment: What a joke to have this crap as default. And then place it under Annotations ?? So intuitive and dumb.

Comment: Works in my Eclipse version: 2019-12 (4.14.0) in Linux.

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure I understand what you mean, but this might help,  go to:

Eclipse -> Preferences -> General -> Search there is a line in the right that reads:
"Foreground color for potential matches" and it has a box right next to it where you can change the colors.
You can change the color of the search.
Otherwise, you can also change the colors of what Eclipse highlights by going to:

Eclipse -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Match Highlight background color
and change the color there.

Hope this helps!
You can also look at this webpage:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Faccessibility%2Ffontsandcolors.htm

Answer (score 9):

This may not be true for all modes, but I'm using Eclipse with Flash Builder plugin on Mac, and it turned out I had to modify the current selection highlight:

General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Selection Background Color

Comment: I needed to do this to see the current search match while <CTRL-F> searching through a file in Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, Version: Kepler Service Release 2, Build id: 20140224-0627 after inverting my colour scheme.

Answer (score 5):

Also in the **search** results window (that lists all the findings in a tree), the background color is under a different setting: `Windows->Preferences->General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts->Match highlighting background color`.

Answer (score 4):

You can change search background color like this: (works for Luna and previous versions)

In the Eclipse menu bar: Windows->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations
Then scroll down to "Search Results" and set the highlighted text color.

Comment: This is the one that actually changes the colors of matches inside of your class files

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I will add my findings. I'm using a MacBook Pro
Using Eclipse Mars.1, while I do a 'text' search (using Emacs). To set the search highlight (or background) color I do the following:
`Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors` see the `Appearance color options` section. Highlight the `Selection background color` and use the color palette to set your desired color.
It is somewhat frustrating as the only way I could get this to work is to restart Eclipse. After the restart I am happy.

Comment: I should state that I'm in PyDev Perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Same as @bityz's answer, except for me the annotation which mattered was "Occurrences". I tried this on Eclipse 4.3 Kepler.

Answer (score 1):

To highlight the matching keywords in Juno

Windows->Preferences->General->Text Editor-.Annotations-> in Annotation Types box, look for Write Occurrences. Change the color there.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean (as I think you do) how do you change the highlight colour of strings that match what you select in an editor (e.g. you double-click on 'filename' and Eclipse highlights other references to 'filename' in a dull grey background), then the following post answers this:
[Eclipse: How do you change the highlight color of the currently selected method/expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434363/eclipse-how-do-you-change-the-highlight-color-of-the-currently-selected-method)

In a nutshell, you want:
* General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations
* Look for "Occurrences" in the Annotation types list and change it from grey to your favourite colour!

Comment: When you search in code, the current match is highlighted differently from the others. To change the "others" background in C++ code, I had to change the "C/C++ Occurrences" annotation color. There were several other tags named "blah occurrences", but only this one allowed me to read highlighted matches again when scrolling away.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found, if you are looking at C++ code (at least in Eclipse Mars 2), changing the following option will set the highlight color of all occurrences of your current (or most recent) search, in case this is what you are looking for:

General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations->C/C++ Occurrences

Why oh why this is not in the C++ preferences pane I will never know.