# Changing highlighting color in a theme from Eclipse color theme

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm using Eclipse Color Theme plugin and it works great. I have only one issue. Sometimes when Eclipse highlights fragments of code it just doesn't seem readable. For example when Eclipse highlights search results it looks like this:

[image]

The name "Product" is hardly visible in the highlight. Is there any way to tune highlight color settings in Eclipse Color Theme?

PS. I'm using default themes that I got after installing the plugin. I didn't download any custom themes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can adjust the highlight colors directly in Eclipse.

On the right side of your code you see the color mark for the search results (red arrow).
If you right-click on this mark the entry "Preferences" shows up.
[image: Screenshot of Code with higlights]

This will take you to the Preferences Dialog: General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations
[image: Screenshot of Preferences Dialog]

If you adjust the colors for Occurences and Search Results this should do the trick for you.

Comment: Can one set LogCat line selector color as well? I know how to change different logcat levels colors but can't find selection color.. It might be windows dependent system color no?

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot, it wasn't obvious which annotation type otherwise. I kept trying to change search when I needed to change occurrences.

Answer (score -1):

The annotation "Write Occurrences" is also important! (The bottom, not shown in the picture)
Here you can set how the highlighting acts for the live Word Search (directly typing a word identical string are indeed highlighted by Eclipse to these highlights, it is so)

Comment: Please post in English only.