# Eclipse: how to get rid of, or change color of, automatic highlighting in code?

Tags: java, android, python, eclipse

I've searched for a solution to this problem but I could not find any. 
I tried myself going into Text Editors, Colors and Fonts, and a bunch of different categories in order to find a way to change the color.

This image shows exactly what the problem is:

http://imgur.com/OVYFl97

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can find this by going into your Preferences, then

General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations

Then you should find Occurrences in the Annotation types list, select Text, and choose the desired color.

OR

Just select some text, right click it, and all the way at the bottom, hit Properties/Preferences. A window should come up where you can change the color!

See this post for more info: [Eclipse: How do you change the highlight color of the currently selected method/expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434363/eclipse-how-do-you-change-the-highlight-color-of-the-currently-selected-method)