# How to fix my Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

My eclipse is highlighting really ugly as shown in the picture. I want to know how to take that off. Also when i run the program, the text in the console appears white, so it blends in with the background color of the console, the only way i can see the text in console is if i highlight the text. I already tried going through settings but i feel that i'm not going to correct place in settings. Please help. Thanks !!

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434363/eclipse-how-do-you-change-the-highlight-color-of-the-currently-selected-method

Comment: Double clicking on a title bar expand the window, as usual. It's reversible. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GUI is totally customizable inside the `Help > Preferences > General > Appearance`.

Something must have been changed, you have some `Restore Default` button that could help you.